# How do you return a specific JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

The file is as such

```
export const countries = [
  {
    alpha2: "TW",
    alpha3: "TWN",
    country: "Taiwan",
    fifa: "TPE",
  },
  {
    alpha2: "AF",
    alpha3: "AFG",
    country: "Afghanistan",
    fifa: "AFG",
  },
```

And I'm trying to do a lookup that matches with the countries and then return a specific object from said country, such as alpha3 string. For example, the country code I'm trying to search is Afghanistan, which should look into the Afghanistan object and return its country code that is alpha3 and return "AFG"

This is my code to search:

```
import { countries } from './countries'

  const countryName = 'Afghanistan'
  const countryCode = countries.find((obj) => {
    if (obj.country === countryName) {
      return obj.alpha3
    }
  })
```

Comment: find returns a boolean so you must return only `obj.country === countryName` and then from the returned object extract the alpha3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jolo's answer is not correct, this is what you need to do:

```
// return the object matching the condition
 const matchingCountry = countries.find((obj) => obj.country === countryName)

// the use of the optional chaining operator protects you from accessing the alpha3 property is your find does not match any object
const matchingCountryCode = matchingCountry?.alpha3
```

And there you go! More on the optional chaining operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. 1 thing to note is that `find()` returns an array item and not the property of an array item.

So just simplify yours steps:

1. find array item
2. get `alpha3` property on the array item you found

```
 // countries.find() returns the array item
 const matchingCountry = countries.find((obj) => {
    if (obj.country === countryName) {
      return obj;
    }
  })

 // optional but advised: handle a situation where no country is found
 if(!matchingCountry){
    console.warn('no country found');
    return; // this ensures no further code will be executed 
 }

 // now you can safely assume matchingCountry is available 
 const matchingCountryCode = matchingCountry.alpha3;
 console.log('success: ', matchingCountryCode)
```